# Excel Date Formula (Closest date of a list to =today() showing up)

Tags: excel, date

I'm trying to create this formula, but i need some help:

I have a list of dates in excel, that basically announce the days we receive a report from a source that we have to send to the final client 3 days after we receive it:

Source 1 - 23/03/15

Source 2 - 24/03/15

Source 3 - 02/04/15

Client - (3 days after receiving a source)

So basically, for source we have a different final client delivery.
But to avoid creating 3 other cells, i would like to do a formula.
Basically the date that should show up in client cell, would be the one more close to =today() and than we would add + 3 days to it. if all dates already passed the =today() would appear ND.

What i having troubles it's to put in formulas "closest date of this list to =today()".

Thank you all.

Comment: Date are stored as double in excel.  So, any double related formula will work : Max, Min, Today()+3

Answer (score 0):

I think a formula such as:

```
=IF(MIN(A:A)<today(),"ND",MIN(A:A)+3)
```

may suit, thought this is assuming 'deadlines' are never missed. So on the day of posing (March 5) the first delivery should be March 26 (depending on the exact interpretation of `3 days after`) since the earliest known receipt date is March 23. On say March 25 the formula result would be "ND" since there would not then be three days between earliest receipt and know delivery requirement. However if the earliest two dates are deleted, the latest (only) remaining receipt date that day would be April 2 and the formula return April 5. No other changes and the formula would, given time, return "ND".